# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_util' when trying to import ImageCms from Pillow

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have this import error when trying to import ImageCms from Pillow. I confirm that PIL is not installed only Pillow version 6.0.0.

Python 3.6.8 |Anaconda, Inc.|

```
In [1]: from PIL import ImageCms                                                
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageCms.py in <module>
     22 try:
---> 23     from PIL import _imagingcms
     24 except ImportError as ex:

ImportError: cannot import name '_imagingcms'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-5649c7a5961e> in <module>
----> 1 from PIL import ImageCms

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/PIL/ImageCms.py in <module>
     25     # Allow error import for doc purposes, but error out when accessing
     26     # anything in core.
---> 27     from _util import deferred_error
     28     _imagingcms = deferred_error(ex)
     29 from PIL._util import isStringType

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_util'
```

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling and reinstalling? I'm unable to replicate your issue using MacOS, python 3.6.8, pillow 6.0.0

Comment: @C.Nivs thanks it worked.